# AWS : Redshift vs traditional dbms

Tags: sql, cloud, amazon-redshift, teradata, rdbms

In traditional DBMS when we try to execute a insert into table and delete from the same table (delete just the data not table) I remember it will result in a deadlock.

With Redshift when I delete data and when I insert Data at the same time I’m able to do it.

How is this possible is the Redshift architecture different from traditional RDBMS when it comes to this type of Deadlock situations.

Comment: Redshift is based on PostgreSQL see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html and with no knowledge on how you created the deadlock notrhow you re-tested that in Redshift I don't think question has an answer.

Comment: How is it different from others? Pls explain more. So in traditional rdmbs we can perform insert into a table and delete data from the same table at the same time right? Pls correct me if am wrong

Comment: Take a moment to consider `how` we can answer. Redshift is just as traditional as PostgreSQL (one of the oldest RDBMS's in use today) and we have absolutely no facts on how you created or re-tested the deadlock situation.

Comment: I don’t face any deadlock in redshift. What am asking is in other db’s will it create a deadlock.

Comment: @Rrr . . . You misunderstand databases and ACID properties.  Concurrent inserts and deletes should work on any database, at least in some circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

There is no real reason that if you try to execute an insert into table and delete form same table, there will be deadlock.

When will deadlock happen in database?

Deadlock happens when there are two sessions- lets call it A and B. If A is holding a lock on row x and waiting for lock row y (before committing) and at same time session B is holding lock on row y and waiting to get lock on row x, there will be deadlock.

Why somebody will hold a lock? It needs to update both rows x and rows y (or in reverse order). There are various documented ways of coding practices by which applications can ensure there is no deadlock caused.

There will be no deadlock if there is simple insert and delete. Even if they are inserting and deleting same record in database (if that is only task these threads are doing). Insert will complete it job and then delete will complete it job.

Also, remember there will never be deadlock if there is no transactions (if queries are auto committed).